# IE Scrolling Issue when Flash wmode is set to opaque

Tags: flash, internet-explorer, facebook, scroll, wmode

This would be for a Flash game within Facebook. If you have a Flash object in IE, when you use the up and down arrow keys it causes the entire browser to scroll. IF you have a game that requires the up and down arrows, this makes it very frustrating to play and just not acceptable.

The wmode is set to opaque and needs to be that way. I understand keeping it at the default would 'fix' this problem, but then the game wouldn't work. Some people say "don't use IE". That would be nice, but that also is not an option.

The part that really stumps me, is that it was working just a few days ago. The solution that worked the first time was to set the container that the Flash object was embedded in with overflow set to auto. But the honeymoon only lasted so long. I'm not sure if Facebook made an API change that might break this. I reverted code that could have possibly the overflow trick not work. No luck, didn't work.

We have also tried to put a text field to grab the focus of the Flash game in AS3, but that trick did not work either.

We have tried to use JS in more than one way, but those were dead ends.

I don't have an example page I can show at this point as the game has yet to be released to the general public.

I'm absolutely stuck at this point and haven't found a solution anywhere. Other people have had this problem but nobody seems to have an answer... if there even is one. The Flash object is losing focus as soon as you push the arrow keys, and no matter what I do I just can't seem to get it to grab focus.

Ideas, thoughts, fixes? Any input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I realise this question is quite old now, but I have also found a possible solution by inserting a scrollPane and setting the alpha to zero. My solution can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11411510/flash-wmode-as3-arrow-key-focus-on-internet-explorer-stacking-order-and-a-p).
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

hey i had this problem too. the text field trick works if you combine it with a listener. i've put the answer [here.](http://rohanlatimer.com.au/blog/2011/03/flash-wmode-and-the-dreaded-ie-scrolling-bug/)

Comment: Little late with the response, but I gave that to one of our Flash dev's and it seems to have worked. Thanks!

Comment: Blog link is broken. Try pasting solutions instead of links. Thanks